# Can I make a tampermonkey userscript reload the page when encountering 500 http codes?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have a userscript that travels from one page to another (using window.location). In about 10% times the page fails to load because of the target website being overhelmed by it's hude traffic (at times) or due to some other reasons.
Refreshing fixes the issue, but it requires my presence, which is very limiting.

How can I get my userscript to reload the page? I haven't found a way to include the chrome's error page into @includes.

Comment: Not possible.  A Chrome extension can do this.  Simplest workaround is to have a master TM script running in a tab/window that opens the new pages in a new tab, window, or iframe.  If the opened pages fail to run their TM instance (you can tell using messages or `GM_set` variables), then the master TM instance will know that an error occurred.

Comment: @BrockAdams, thanks, but how do I make such a master script?

Comment: Search for GM/TM/userscripts Q's that cover iframe communication. Then for Q's about opening links.  The principle is the same for two windows as for a page and an iframe.  All the pieces have been covered in multiple Q's.  I don't have time for a proper answer here.