# Reloading a page when "This site can't be reached"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

If I want chrome to keep auto-reloading the page when it shows "This site can't be reached. xyx.com took too long to respond." unit the page is reached. How should I match the page?

Normally, I would use keyword of the page. Like:

```
var blacklist = ["qwertyuiop"],
    re = new RegExp(blacklist.join('|'), "i");
if (re.test(document.body.textContent)) {
  var win = window.open("","_self");
  location.reload() ;
```

However, this wouldn't actually work until the page is loaded.

Comment: You probably need to write an chrome extension for it to work.

Comment: Essentially a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303027/can-i-make-a-tampermonkey-userscript-reload-the-page-when-encountering-500-http.  I'll try to remember to write up an answer tomorrow (no promises).

Comment: @BrockAdams thanks in advance